# Sum computed column in Django QuerySet

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the following `Contribution` model:

```
class Contribution(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

is it possible, using the Django database API, to reproduce the following SQL statement?

```
SELECT SUM(end_time - start_time) AS total_duration FROM contribution;
```

I've figured out this much:

```
Contribution.objects.aggregate(total_duration=models.Sum( ??? ))
```

but I'm not sure about how to represent the `end_time - start_time` part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, there's a [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10972) for F() objects inside aggregation, but nothing promising.

The only way i see is to workaround by sum in python:

```
sum([x[1]-x[0] for x in Contribution.objects.values_list('start_time', 'end_time')])
```